# Plot more than one series on the same time series using Grafana and MySQL

Tags: mysql, grafana

I have multiple servers reporting a value(Temperature or reliability score). I want to plot them on the same time series. value over time for each metric.

the table looks like this

```
Total Reliability
Time                | value | metric
2021-12-07 08:24:20 | 0.994 | 2787
2021-12-07 08:25:18 | 0.996 | 3129
2021-12-07 08:25:34 | 0.994 | 2787
2021-12-07 08:26:31 | 0.996 | 3129
2021-12-07 08:26:48 | 0.994 | 2787
2021-12-07 08:27:44 | 0.996 | 3129
```

I read a few similar questions but their solution does not work for some reason

```
SELECT
time AS “time”,
reliability as value,
machine_id as metric
FROM machine
WHERE
$__unixEpochFilter(time)
GROUP BY machine_id,time
ORDER BY time asc
```

if I remove the grouping to plot the two columns

[image]

using Grafana v8.2.5 (b57a137acd) and  MySQL Server 8.0.27

Comment: I can do this with a query for each system but as I don't know how many servers there will be or what there machine_IDs will be I need to find a way for tot to group it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metric should be string. It looks like a integer in your case, so hack `machine_id as metric`:

```
CONCAT(machine_id , '') AS metric
```

Use [Grafana MySQL macros](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#macros) for time agreggation. Then final Grafana SQL query with 5m avg aggregation should be:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(time,'5m'),
  AVG(reliability) AS value,
  CONCAT(machine_id, '') AS metric
FROM machine
WHERE $__unixEpochFilter(time)
GROUP BY machine_id, time
ORDER BY time ASC
```

It still may need some small adjustements.

Answer (score 0):

I use this.

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  reliability AS value,
  CONCAT(machine_id, '') AS metric
FROM machine
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time)
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: This selects raw data - it may return a lot of data when you select a longer time range (e.g. 1 month) and your browser may have a problem to process those data (high memory, cpu utilization). Time aggregation is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need "group by"
there is a transform "partition by values" which does separate time serie for each value in the columns selected

[image]

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#partition-by-values